# XeLaTeX and font Libertinus: Missing character for upright T in math mode

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, characters, libertinus

If I compile the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}

\newcommand*{\Gt}{G_{\mathrm{T}}}
\newcommand*{\gt}{g_{\mathrm{T}}}

\begin{document}
Let  $\Gt = \langle \gt \rangle$ be a cyclic group.

Let  $G_{\mathrm{T}} = \langle g_{\mathrm{T}} \rangle$ be a cyclic group.
\end{document}
```

I get the result

[image: Resulting PDF]

The expected result is to see a capital italic math G followed by a upright T in the suffix.

The log says

`Missing character: There is no ⪢ in font [LibertinusMath-Regular.otf]/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;!`

What is wrong here? Why does the similar code work for the small g?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an invisible character hiding in there?  You could make this example even more minimal by changing `\Gt` to its equivalent `G_{\mathrm{T}}` and `\gt` to `g_{\mathrm{T}}`.  That might narrow down where the problem occurs.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, I am. I even checked in a hex editor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You chose the wrong command name. In `unicode-math-table.tex` we find

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02AA2}{\Gt}{\mathrel}{double nested greater-than}%
```

The table is read at begin document and, unfortunately, it overrides commands without warning.

You *might* do

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\Gt}{\Group_{\symrm{T}}}}
```

but my advice is to choose a different name.

Note that with `unicode-math` you should use `\symrm` rather than `\mathrm`.

[image]